# Inversion of vector for every vector in vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

By defintion of vector space for every vector a exist vector b such as

```
a + b = 0
```

If we chose vector with scalar $Z_{2}$ and set of vectors ({1,0},{0,1}) and operations + and * the vector space should consist of

{(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)}

But in this case there does not exist any vector for vector a that would result in

```
a + b = 0
```

Did I make a mistake in my example or did I overlook something?

Thanks for clarification/explanation

Comment: $(1,1)+(1,1)=(0,0)$; similarly, $(1,0)+(1,0)=(0,0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the field of scalars is $\mathbb{F}_2$ then each vector is its additive inverse: $v + v = 2v = 0$ since $2 = 0$ in $\mathbb{F}_2$

Comment: So when i am using modulo 2 as Scalar vectors are in modulo too?